# Property with special characters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to write in my object some properties with the `'` character
e.g.

```
const championsList = {
    Kha'Zi: '...',
};
```

How can I do that?

Comment: While Yannick's answer will work, I would question whether you really *need* to use special characters for this. Your code will be a lot cleaner if you can avoid it.

Comment: I'm getting these data from a site for a bot i need to write it in this way

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by wrapping the property in quotation marks, having a property like this does mean you'll have to access it using brackets:

```js
const championsList = {
  "Kha'Zi": "...",
};
console.log(championsList[ "Kha'Zi" ]);
```

Comment: You don't need the brackets, just the quotes. Brackets are only needed if the property name is a dynamic expression.

Comment: @Barmar yup, I'm an idiot. Thanks for the comment, edited.

Comment: if i set a variable:
let scelta = "Kha'Zix";
const championsList = {
    "kha'Zi": '....',
};
let sceltaUrl = championsList[scelta];
console.log(sceltaUrl);

it returns undefined

Comment: @gsfs note that you didn't capitalize "Kha'Zi" in your object there. And actually, `scelta` is equal to `Kha'Zix` not `Kha'Zi`.